# Postgres: multiple tables vs single table and multiple indexes

Tags: postgresql

The current applications i'm working on have multiple entities, let's call them `A`, `B` and `C`, each of them uniquely identified by an `id` and a `group_id` of the group they belong to. 
Currently all the instances of these entities are stored in a single table with the following fields:

```
id: primary key
group_id: id of the group 
data: jsonb field containing all the custom entity fields
```

I have a concern about storing all the entities in a single table, first because of the size of the table itself, and then since they are used in different applications as well they all need to be indexed differently since the fields differ between instances of `A` and `B` or `C`.

I'm thinking about two approaches:

- separating the entities in different tables, one for each group_id, add entity-specific indexes for each table.
- keep the instances in a single table, set an index for `group_id` and then different indexes based on the `group_id` and considering the fields of each entity that have to be indexed.

What is the best approach in this case? or is there any other option i'm missing?

Comment: You talk about different fields per entity but currently you just have a json blob. Are you planning to keep it in a single blob or you going to create new fields for the unjsonified (that's probably a word) data?

Comment: @eurotrash keeping them as a json blob.

Comment: Is it jsonb rather than json then?

Comment: @eurotrash it's `jsonb` indeed

Comment: Ok - this is purely my opinion then based on nothing other than personal preferences. I would keep them in the same table, since they are the same structurally and to an extent conceptually. Then create indexes on group_id + jsonb fields. I don't really have strong feelings on it though, I'd be happy either way. Probably would be best to try both, populate with data, and run some performance tests.  If the fields were actual table fields I'd definitely move them to different tables.